# Upstart: pipe the output of multiple commands

Tags: upstart

I try to detect if there is a network link (cable plugged/unplugged) in an upstart script (Ubuntu 12.04). Here the relevant part of my script (which didndt work):

```
script
if  [ /sbin/ethtool eth0 | /bin/grep "Link detected: yes" > /dev/null ] ; then
    exec prog1
else
    exec prog2
fi

end script
```

(try to start prog1 if there is a link otherwise prog2.) How to fix that?

Comment: I can't help feeling that there is a better way of doing this using the appropriate upstart signal(s) (`net-device-up` maybe?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use

```
if /sbin/ethtool eth0 | /bin/grep -q "Link detected: yes" ; then
    exec prog1
else
    exec prog2
fi
```

The -q argument to grep will discard stdout, and the if statement checks the status of the command it runs. `[ /sbin/ethtool eth0 | /bin/grep -q "Link detected: yes" ]` is not a valid command, because `[` is actually a program that accepts arguments like grep. So `[` cannot understand `/sbin/ethtool eth0 | /bin/grep -q "Link detected: yes"` and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that Upstart runs shell code in /bin/sh (which is Dash), not /bin/bash. If you put your code into `sh`, it doesn't work:

```
$ if  [ /sbin/ethtool eth0 | /bin/grep "Link detected: yes" > /dev/null ]; then echo cheese; fi
sh: 9: [: missing ]
/bin/grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

So there's a syntax issue in there. Rather than use the implicit status code check that bash uses, I'd consider breaking things up like so:

```
/sbin/ethtool eth0 | /bin/grep "Link detected: yes" > /dev/null
if  [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo cheese; fi
```

The above works for me in `sh`.

---

Or you could force bash behaviour by [wrapping it in a bash loader](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#changing-the-default-shell):

```
script
/bin/bash <<EOT
    if  [ /sbin/ethtool eth0 | /bin/grep "Link detected: yes" > /dev/null ]; then echo cheese; fi
EOT
end script
```